# R Package Installation Trouble

Tags: r, installation, package, homebrew

When attempting to install the R package "nleqslv", I receive the following error message:

```
install.packages("nleqslv", type = 'source')
Installing package into ‘/opt/homebrew/lib/R/4.3/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/nleqslv_3.3.5.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 82473 bytes (80 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 80 KB

* installing *source* package ‘nleqslv’ ...
** package ‘nleqslv’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
using C compiler: ‘Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.0.40.1)’
using Fortran compiler: ‘GNU Fortran (Homebrew GCC 13.2.0) 13.2.0’
using SDK: ‘MacOSX14.0.sdk’
clang -I"/opt/homebrew/Cellar/r/4.3.1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -I"/opt/homebrew/lib/R/4.3/site-library/Rcpp/include/"  -I"/opt/homebrew/lib/R/4.3/site-library/RcppEigen/include/"  -I"/opt/homebrew/lib/R/4.3/site-library/RcppEigen/include/unsupported"  -I"/opt/homebrew/lib/R/4.3/site-library/BH/include" -I"/opt/homebrew/lib/R/4.3/site-library/StanHeaders/include/src/"  -I"/opt/homebrew/lib/R/4.3/site-library/StanHeaders/include/"  -I"/opt/homebrew/lib/R/4.3/site-library/RcppParallel/include/"  -I"/opt/homebrew/lib/R/4.3/site-library/rstan/include" -DEIGEN_NO_DEBUG  -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS  -DBOOST_PENDING_INTEGER_LOG2_HPP  -DSTAN_THREADS  -DUSE_STANC3 -DSTRICT_R_HEADERS  -DBOOST_PHOENIX_NO_VARIADIC_EXPRESSION  -DBOOST_NO_AUTO_PTR  -include '/opt/homebrew/lib/R/4.3/site-library/StanHeaders/include/stan/math/prim/fun/Eigen.hpp'  -D_REENTRANT -DRCPP_PARALLEL_USE_TBB=1   -I/opt/homebrew/opt/gettext/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/xz/include -I/opt/homebrew/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -c init.c -o init.o
In file included from <built-in>:1:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/lib/R/4.3/site-library/StanHeaders/include/stan/math/prim/fun/Eigen.hpp:22:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/lib/R/4.3/site-library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Dense:1:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/lib/R/4.3/site-library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Core:88:
/opt/homebrew/lib/R/4.3/site-library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/Macros.h:628:1: error: unknown type name 'namespace'
namespace Eigen {
^
/opt/homebrew/lib/R/4.3/site-library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/Macros.h:628:16: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
namespace Eigen {
               ^
               ;
In file included from <built-in>:1:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/lib/R/4.3/site-library/StanHeaders/include/stan/math/prim/fun/Eigen.hpp:22:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/lib/R/4.3/site-library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Dense:1:
/opt/homebrew/lib/R/4.3/site-library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Core:96:10: fatal error: 'complex' file not found
#include <complex>
         ^~~~~~~~~
3 errors generated.
make: *** [init.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘nleqslv’
* removing ‘/opt/homebrew/lib/R/4.3/site-library/nleqslv’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘nleqslv’ had non-zero exit status
```

I am not sure if it is related to the fact that I am using homebrew on macOS or not.

Downloading and attempting to install from the tar.gz file and the macOS binaries file from the CRAN page directly does not work either. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not an answer since I am not a Mac user but when it comes to errors involving contributed packages, it's a good practice to try to contact `maintainer("nleqslv")`.

Comment: These errors seem to happen a lot when people install R via homebrew. It just does not do the linking correctly. Is there a reason you are not using the official CRAN release?

Comment: Need a toolchain adjustment: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/tools/ Seems that using the proper C and Fortran compilers might be the first step: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/tools/gfortran-4.2.3.pkg and https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/tools/clang-8.0.0.pkg

Comment: @MrFlick I uninstalled rstudio and r from homebrew, then installed directly from the official CRAN sites and was able to install the package (and others) successfully. The original intent was for convenience of updating, but this was too much of a hassle for it to be worth it.

Comment: @IRTFM Your solution may or may not have worked, I didn't try it out myself as I just decided to install r and rstudio outside of homebrew, and was able to install the package successfully.